# EF Core 3.1 running on .Net framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We have recently been asked to replace our business layer (type library 4.7.2) which is using an old ORM with EF Core.  Our UI project is a WebForms implementation running on .Net 4.7.2.

We begun by trying to make the business layer with .Net Core and EF Core 6 but you can not reference a .Net Core project from a .Net framework project.

I see on this link [EF Core Implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/platforms)

that we can run EF Core 3.1 on .Net Framework 4.7.2.  I have quickly created a project and indeed this seems to work.

I guess my question here is - the UI project will always remain as a WebForms project but are we wasting our time using EF Core 3.1 as at some point this will lose support?  I cant seem to find any pathway where EF Core is continously integrated back to the .Net framework.

Comment: EF Core 3.1 is EOL on December 3, 2022... https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/

Comment: Is it ... ok so my point exactly.  What are we supposed to do ....?

Comment: If you are still doing active development on your application you may want to invest time in upgrading. Framework 4.8 has been out for some time. .Net6 supports Winforms. EOL doesn't mean your existing app will quit working, just that you cant get support from Microsoft. No security patches, fixes, or updates.

Comment: I think .Net Standard 2.1 works with EF Core 5 but not with .Net framework - .Net standard 2.0 works with .Net framework but only EF Core 3.1 (I think)

Comment: Okay, good point. As to whether Microsoft will support Entity Framework Core on .NET Framework in the future, only Microsoft knows. Others might have opinions on whether they will or not, but Stack Overflow isn't for opinion based questions unfortunately. I feel for you, as we too have a large legacy Web Forms app on .NET Framework. Best thing to do is either bite the bullet and upgrade to .NET Core, or slowly start porting functionality bit by bit into a .NET Core site you run alongside it. Not only is EF Core on .NET Framework likely a dead platform, but .NET Framework is a dead platform too

Comment: We have considered just creating a Web API solution based on .Net core.  However, it seems a bit counter-intuative to go go from WebForms code behind to hit the Web API.  Apart from the double hit - it is a fair bit more work to make this happen